# CHSH violation and entanglement of quantum states

Tags: research-level, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, non-locality

How is the violation of the usual CHSH inequality by a quantum state related to the entanglement of that quantum state?

Say we know that exist Hermitian and unitary operators $A_{0}$, $A_{1}$, $B_{0}$ and $B_{1}$ such that
$$\mathrm{tr} ( \rho ( A_{0}\otimes B_{0} + A_{0} \otimes B_{1} + A_{1}\otimes B_{0} - A_{1} \otimes B_{1} )) = 2+ c > 2,$$
then we know that the state $\rho$ must be entangled.  But what else do we know?  If we know the form of the operators $A_{j}$ and $B_{j}$, then there is certainly more to be said (see e.g. http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v87/i23/e230402 ).  However, what if I do not want to assume anything about the measurements performed?

Can the value of $c$ be used to give a rigourous lower bound on any of the familar entanglement measures, such as log-negativity or relative entropy of entanglement?

Clearly, one could argue in a slightly circular fashion and define an entanglement measure as the maximal possible CHSH violation over all possible measurements.  But is there anything else one can say?

Comment: Your questions is answered here: [arXiv:0907.2170](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2170). BTW, _device-independent_ is the key phrase to search for.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Thanks for your comment. I had not thought of goggling for "device-independent" and was not aware of that paper.  It seems to answer my question, though I'm still going through some of the details.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: Perhaps you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a paper [C.-E. Bardyn et al., PRA 80(6): 062327](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.80.062327) (2009), [arXiv:0907.2170](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2170), they discuss constrains on the state, given how much the CHSH equality is violated ($S=2+c$), but without putting any assumptions on the operator used.

In general people consider schemes, when operators (for a Bell-type measurement) are random or one or more parties cannot be trusted. One of the key phrases is *device-independent* and maybe also *loophole-free* (as even a slight misalignment of operators may change the results dramatically).